# Shortest path with vertex capacity

Tags: reference-request, shortest-path

I have an undirected graph where each edge $e=\{u,v\}$ has a positive weight $w_{uv}$ and each vertex $v$ has a positive capacity $c_v$. There are two special vertices: a source vertex $s$ and a destination vertex $d$. A vehicle has $n$ items where item $i$ has a load $\ell_{iv}$ when placed on vertex $v\notin\{s,d\}$.

The vehicle needs to place all of its items on the vertices of the shortest (in terms of edge weights) path from $s$ to $d$ such that the capacity of each vertex in this shortest path is respected, i.e., the loads of the items $I$ placed on vertex $v$ are less than $c_v$ ($\sum_{i\in I}\ell_{iv}\leq c_v$).

Is this problem known in the literature?

I only found the version called [the shortest capacitated paths problem](https://www.gerad.ca/%7Ealainh/Bounds.pdf) where the capacity constraints are on the edges and not on the vertices.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I reformulated the problem. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: What does it mean for a vehicle to place its items on a path?  Why isn't the solution to just check for which vertices the capacity is restricted, throw away all other vertices, and then find the shortest path in the resulting graph?  If the answer were that simple I'm sure you would have thought of it, so I suspect I have misunderstood the problem somehow.

Comment: The vehicle can place on the vertices of the path the items. If I remove the vertices that do not respect the capacity, how do I guarantee that the resulting graph would give the optimal solution.